# What is the Swift equivalent of isEqualToString in Objective-C?

Tags: string, swift

I am trying to run the code below:

```swift
import UIKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var username : UITextField = UITextField()
@IBOutlet var password : UITextField = UITextField()

@IBAction func loginButton(sender : AnyObject) {

    if username .isEqual("") || password.isEqual(""))
    {
        println("Sign in failed. Empty character")
    }
}
```

My previous code was in Objective-C, which was working fine:

```
 if([[self.username text] isEqualToString: @""] ||
    [[self.password text] isEqualToString: @""] ) {
```

I assume I cannot use `isEqualToString` in Swift.

Answer (score 461, accepted):

With Swift you don't need anymore to check the equality with `isEqualToString`

You can now use `==`

Example:

```
let x = "hello"
let y = "hello"
let isEqual = (x == y)
```

now isEqual is `true`.

Comment: `===` is identity operators whereas `==` is equality operator (by default call `isEqual:` on NSObject and its subclasses)

Comment: Yes, sorry, "equality", not identity. Wrong word :)

Comment: But, unless I'm missing something, it doesn't seem you can test the *identity* between Strings: `'String' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'`.

Comment: @user1040049 You can't compare String using === operator because String in swift is of type struct not class. If you type cast your text/string as NSString you can compare using === operator.

Comment: @JJSaccolo you really misleading with identity part. This question about `String` comparison. Xcode 6.4 returns you an error `Binary operator '===' cannot be applied to two String operands`

Comment: Please update the answer. Swift compiler will return an error ("Binary operator === cannot be applied to two string operands") if we try to compare the identity two strings.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I removed the section about identity comparison.

Answer (score 52):

Use **==** operator instead of `isEqual`

## Comparing Strings

Swift provides three ways to compare String values: string equality, prefix equality, and suffix equality.

**String Equality**

Two String values are considered equal if they contain exactly the same characters in the same order:

```
let quotation = "We're a lot alike, you and I."
let sameQuotation = "We're a lot alike, you and I."
if quotation == sameQuotation {
    println("These two strings are considered equal")
}
// prints "These two strings are considered equal"
.
.
.
```

For more read [official documentation of Swift *(search Comparing Strings)*.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/StringsAndCharacters.html)

Answer (score 13):

I addition to `@JJSaccolo` answer, you can create custom `equals` method as new String extension like:

```
extension String {
     func isEqualToString(find: String) -> Bool {
        return String(format: self) == find
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
let a = "abc"
let b = "abc"

if a.isEqualToString(b) {
     println("Equals")
}
```

For sure original operator `==` might be better (works like in Javascript) but for me `isEqual` method gives some code clearness that we compare Strings

Hope it will help to someone,

Comment: not sure if it should be done like this when there is Comparable protocol https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/comparable

Answer (score 9):

In Swift, the == operator is equivalent to Objective C's isEqual: method (it calls the isEqual method instead of just comparing pointers, and there's a new === method for testing that the pointers are the same), so you can just write this as:

```
if username == "" || password == ""
{
    println("Sign in failed. Empty character")
}
```

Comment: while this works in swift - it will cause havoc in objc if / when username is nil. As suggested above - use username.isEmpty and there's an equivalent isEmpty macro for objective c somewhere.

Comment: In Swift, unless the username is declared as String? (aka Optional<String>) then it can't be nil. In Objective C you can just say if ([username length] == 0 || [password length] == 0) { ... } to cover nil or empty cases.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, it feels like swift is trying to promote strings to be treated less like objects and more like values. However this doesn't mean under the hood swift doesn't treat strings as objects, as am sure you all noticed that you can still invoke methods on strings and use their properties.

For example:-

```
//example of calling method (String to Int conversion)
let intValue = ("12".toInt())
println("This is a intValue now \(intValue)")


//example of using properties (fetching uppercase value of string)
let caUpperValue = "ca".uppercaseString
println("This is the uppercase of ca \(caUpperValue)")
```

In objectC you could pass the reference to a string object through a variable, on top of calling methods on it, which pretty much establishes the fact that strings are pure objects.

Here is the catch when you try to look at String as objects, in swift you cannot pass a string object by reference through a variable. Swift will always pass a brand new copy of the string. Hence, strings are more commonly known as value types in swift. In fact, two string literals will not be identical (===). They are treated as two different copies.

```
let curious = ("ca" === "ca")
println("This will be false.. and the answer is..\(curious)")
```

As you can see we are starting to break aways from the conventional way of thinking of strings as objects and treating them more like values. Hence .isEqualToString which was treated as an identity operator for string objects is no more a valid as you can never get two identical string objects in Swift. You can only compare its value, or in other words check for equality(==).

```
 let NotSoCuriousAnyMore = ("ca" == "ca")
 println("This will be true.. and the answer is..\(NotSoCuriousAnyMore)")
```

This gets more interesting when you look at the mutability of string objects in swift. But thats for another question, another day. Something you should probably look into, cause its really interesting. :) Hope that clears up some confusion. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

For the UITextField text comparison I am using below code and working fine for me, let me know if you find any error.

```
if(txtUsername.text.isEmpty || txtPassword.text.isEmpty)
{
    //Do some stuff
}
else if(txtUsername.text == "****" && txtPassword.text == "****")
{
    //Do some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Swift the `isEmpty` function it will check if the string is empty.

```
 if username.isEmpty || password.isEmpty {
      println("Sign in failed. Empty character")
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

One important point is that Swift's `==` on strings might not be equivalent to Objective-C's `-isEqualToString:`. The peculiarity lies in differences in how strings are represented between Swift and Objective-C.

Just look on this example:

```
let composed = "Ö" // U+00D6 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS
let decomposed = composed.decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping // (U+004F LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O) + (U+0308 COMBINING DIAERESIS)

composed.utf16.count // 1
decomposed.utf16.count // 2

let composedNSString = composed as NSString
let decomposedNSString = decomposed as NSString

decomposed == composed // true, Strings are equal
decomposedNSString == composedNSString // false, NSStrings are not
```

`NSString`'s are represented as a sequence of UTF–16 code units (roughly read as an array of UTF-16 (fixed-width) code units). Whereas Swift `String`s are conceptually sequences of "Characters", where "Character" is something that abstracts extended grapheme cluster (read Character = any amount of Unicode code points, usually something that the user sees as a character and text input cursor jumps around).

The next thing to mention is Unicode. There is a lot to write about it, but here we are interested in something called "canonical equivalence". Using Unicode code points, visually the same "character" can be encoded in more than one way. For example, "Á" can be represented as a precomposed "Á" or as decomposed A + ◌́ (that's why in example `composed.utf16` and `decomposed.utf16` had different lengths). A good thing to read on that is [this great article](http://reedbeta.com/blog/programmers-intro-to-unicode/).

`-[NSString isEqualToString:]`, according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1407803-isequaltostring), compares NSStrings code unit by code unit, so:

```
[Á] != [A, ◌́]
```

Swift's String `==` [compares characters by canonical equivalence](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string).

```
[ [Á] ] == [ [A, ◌́] ]
```

In swift the above example will return true for Strings. That's why `-[NSString isEqualToString:]` is not equivalent to Swift's String ==. Equivalent pure Swift comparison could be done by comparing String's UTF-16 Views:

```
decomposed.utf16.elementsEqual(composed.utf16) // false, UTF-16 code units are not the same
decomposedNSString == composedNSString // false, UTF-16 code units are not the same
decomposedNSString.isEqual(to: composedNSString as String) // false, UTF-16 code units are not the same
```

Also, there is a difference between `NSString == NSString` and `String == String` in Swift. The `NSString ==` will cause isEqual and UTF-16 code unit by code unit comparison, where as `String ==` will use canonical equivalence:

```
decomposed == composed // true, Strings are equal
decomposed as NSString == composed as NSString // false, UTF-16 code units are not the same
```

And the whole example:

```
let composed = "Ö" // U+00D6 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS
let decomposed = composed.decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping // (U+004F LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O) + (U+0308 COMBINING DIAERESIS)

composed.utf16.count // 1
decomposed.utf16.count // 2

let composedNSString = composed as NSString
let decomposedNSString = decomposed as NSString

decomposed == composed // true, Strings are equal
decomposedNSString == composedNSString // false, NSStrings are not

decomposed.utf16.elementsEqual(composed.utf16) // false, UTF-16 code units are not the same
decomposedNSString == composedNSString // false, UTF-16 code units are not the same
decomposedNSString.isEqual(to: composedNSString as String) // false, UTF-16 code units are not the same
```