# Closure identity in swift: unregister observing closure

Tags: swift, closures, observer-pattern, key-value-observing, observable

When rethinking my everyday programming patterns to be more *swifty*, there is one, that I really struggle with: **observing changes**. After a lot of thinking and research I have yet to find a **satisfying solution**. That is one,

- that is easy to use,
- leverages the full potential of swift's strong type system,
- is compatible with value types and
- allows for static dispatch.

*Maybe the latter one is not possible and that's the reason why my search is unsuccessful so far. If so, I would like to know why?*

Some of the **work-arounds** I found so far:

1. [SO: Observer Pattern in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30976995/observer-pattern-in-swift) (Using `Any` or objective_c runtime functionality)
2. [Solving the binding problem with Swift](http://five.agency/solving-the-binding-problem-with-swift/) (IMHO rather awkward to use)
3. The ones based on closures e.g [Answer by Airspeed Velocity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31371469/4105099)

The third one is so far the one that ticks the most boxes it's type safe, straight forward to use, and compatible with value types. For reference:

```
// central part is an observable protocol that can be fulfilled by
// any observable type.
protocol Observable {
    associatedtype Value
    func register(f: Value->())
}

// this would be implemented like
struct ObeservableInt: Observable {
    // observable value
    var value: Int {
        didSet {
            // inform all observers
            for f in observers {
                f(value)
            }
        }
     }

     var observers = Array<Int->()>()

     mutating func register(f: Int->()) {
         observers.append(f)
     }
}
```

So far so good. But what happens if our observer is not needed any more? To avoid a memory leak we should unregister it. But this is seemingly not possible with this architecture. Despite being reference types, [closures don't have a reliable identity](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160222/010872.html). That is unless we [force dynamic dispatch by annotation with `@objc_block`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25594273/4105099). Another alternative is to [return a token from `register(f:)`](http://moreindirection.blogspot.de/2014/08/nsnotificationcenter-swift-and-blocks.html) and use that in an the `unregister(token:)` call.

So my question is, are there any **better alternatives** regarding the listed criteria? If not, **which one of the two solutions** `@objc_block` or using token **is the preferred one**?